# Why do MongoDB ISODate and Date behave differently for getDay()?

Tags: mongodb

Try this in a Mongo 2.6.4 shell:

```
> tues = ISODate("2014-07-01")
ISODate("2014-07-01T00:00:00Z")
> tues.getDay()
1
> tues = new Date(2014, 6, 1)
ISODate("2014-07-01T04:00:00Z")
> tues.getDay()
2
```

i.e. create an `ISODate` for July 1, 2014 (a Tuesday), and run `getDay()` to get the day of the week and get 1, then create the same date with a standard Javascript `Date` and, as expected with Javascript, `getDay()` returns 2.

From the Mongo docs, it seems `ISODate` is simply a wrapper for `Date`. I can't find any documentation saying it behaves differently for `getDay()`. Is this intended behavior? If so, why? A bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDay` is giving you the day based on the local timezone. I am suspecting you are in U.S. EDT timezone. So in the first case, your local time is still 2014-06-30 20:00:00 EDT (Mon).

Comment: Right! I'm in New York.

Comment: Isn't this strange behavior though? Why would a date print out as 2014-07-01 as it does above yet use a different time zone for getDay?

Comment: @Ghopper21 Not strange at all. The way you are using `Date` here creates as local time zone. If you want to use `Date` to create a UTC time use `new Date("2014-07-01")` which works the same as the ISODate helper.